# converting lat long to Address in javascript

Tags: ruby, google-maps, geocode, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to change the display in a markerWindow from the lat long to an address. I am having trouble understanding the Google API on how to do this. I am open to using the Google API or the geocoder gem, whichever works better. I am just not sure how to include either of them into my code.

```
    var map;
  function initialize() {

    //initializing map view
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.32657009662249, -71.06678009033203),
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      panControl: true,
      zoomControl: true,

      scaleControl: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
      panControl: true,
      panControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
      },
      zoomControl: true,
      zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
      }
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        myOptions);

    //BIKE STUFF
    var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
    bikeLayer.setMap(map);

    <% @Reports.each do |x|%>
      addMarker(<%= x.latitude %>, <%=x.longitude%>);
    <% end %>
  }

  function addMarker(lat, long){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
          map: map,
          title: 'REPORT'
        });
        //DROP PIN
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
        marker.setTitle('DROP');
        //DROP MARKER INFOWINDOW
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
          infowindow.open(map, this);
          marker = this
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content:"Lat: " + lat + ", Long: " + long
        });
        //CLOSING MARKER INFOWINDOW
        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,'closeclick',function(){
          infowindow.close(map, this); //removes the marker
        });
    }    
  console.log("message")
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Instead where it says content in the InfoWindow I would like it to display the address.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your existing code, one way to display the address of the marker is to store it in your database (or whatever you are querying to get the latitude and longitude),  then pass it in to the "addMarker" call (after changing the addMarker function to accept a third argument containing the address.

Not tested:

```
function addMarker(lat, long, address){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
      map: map,
      title: 'REPORT'
    });
    //DROP PIN
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
    marker.setTitle('DROP');
    //DROP MARKER INFOWINDOW
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
      infowindow.open(map, this);
      marker = this
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content:address
    });
```

If you don't already have the address stored, you can use Google's geocoding service as a reverse geocoder to translate lat/lng to address.

EDIT:
You can look at this ["article"](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat) from the documentation which discusses geocoding strategies, the geocoder and reverse geocoder services are similar and the same quotas and rate limits apply to them.

- Here is [the documentation on the reverse geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding)
- Here is [the example from the documentation for reverse geocoding (client-side)](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)
- Here is [an example which uses the reverse geocoder to return the address of a dragged marker and displays the returned address in the infowindow](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_revgeo.html)

Comment: "ou can use Google's geocoding service as a reverse geocoder to translate lat/lng to address." is the part I am unsure how to do

Comment: Do you have the lat/lng coordinates stored in a database?  Do you not have associated address there also?  Where did the points you want to add markers to come from?

Comment: yes my coordinates are stored in a database. All I have in my database are the lat and long coordinates. I would like to display on my map these points but in the infoWindow the address instead of the coordinates. But I am unsure how to turn the coordinates into the address.